# How to extract a factor from equation and rearrange the equation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I want to extract a factor from the equations, it's not a common factor, just a factor defined by myself, like this:
(a*c+b) --> c*(a+b/c)
I have tried `Factor`,`FactorTerms`,`Eliminate`, but it do not work as I expect, if the factor do not contained in the terms, it could not be extracted, like:
b=c*(b/c)
I turn to MATHEMATICA for its ability on symbolic calculations, I want to replace pen and paper with the computer program, for convenient and accuracy. Sometimes I need to rearrange the equations to extract some factors or apply some math skills, but the MATHEMATICA always automatically simplify my expression.
This is my equation:

```
-((b La r \[Omega] - b k La^2 \[Omega]^2)/(
  g h k w + g h k^3 La^2 w)) == 1
```

I want to extract `(\[Omega]^2*b)/(k^2*g*h*w)` and put this part on one side and the other parts on the other side, like this:

```
(\[Omega]^2*b)/(k^2*g*h*w) == the other part
```

I have tried:

```
eq11=-((b La r \[Omega] - b k La^2 \[Omega]^2)/(
  g h k w + g h k^3 La^2 w)) == 1
eq12 = Times[(\[Omega]^2*b)/(k^2*g*h*w), 
  Divide[eq11[[1]], (\[Omega]^2*b)/(k^2*g*h*w)]]
```

and

```
factorOut[fac_][expr_] := 
 Replace[expr, p_Plus :> fac Simplify[p/fac], All]
factorOut[(\[Omega]^2*b)/(k^2*g*h*w)][eq11]
```

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate it if who can fix my problem

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks those who provide help, all of the answers are very great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this way

```
eq = -((b La r \[Omega] - b k La^2 \[Omega]^2)/(g h k w + 
   g h k^3 La^2 w)) == 1

sub1 = (b \[Omega]^2)/(g h k^2 w)

eq2 = eq[[1]]*sub2/sub1 == eq[[2]]

sol = First@Solve[eq2, sub2]

(*     {sub2 -> ((1 + k^2 La^2) \[Omega])/(k La (-r + k La \[Omega]))}     *)

sub1 == sub2 /. sol // Simplify

(*   (b \[Omega]^2)/(g h k^2 w) == 
-((\[Omega] + k^2 La^2 \[Omega])/(k La r - k^2 La^2 \[Omega]))   *)

sub1 == sub2 /. sol // Simplify[#, eq] &

(*   True   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no special built-in function doing this. You can use the following customwritten one:

```
factor[expr_, fact_, funExpr_ : Expand, funFact_ : Identity] := 
 Module[{a = fact, b = expr/fact},
  funFact[Evaluate[a]]*funExpr[Evaluate[b]]]
```

Here `expr` is the expression to factor, the `fact` is the factor to take out of the parentheses, `funExpr`is an optional function to apply to the rest of the expression after the factorization. By default, it is `Expand`. `funFact` is an optional function to apply to the factor if needed. By default, it is `Identity`.

Returning to your expression:

```
 expr = -((b La r \[Omega] - b k La^2 \[Omega]^2)/(g h k w + 
           g h k^3 La^2 w)); 
factor[expr, (\[Omega]^2*b)/(k^2*g*h*w), Simplify, HoldForm]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the simplest way to make desired is to do it semi-manually:

```
aaa=-((b La r \[Omega] - b k La^2 \[Omega]^2)/(g h k w + g h k^3 La^2 w));
bbb=\[Omega] b/(k^2 g h w);
res=Simplify[aaa/bbb]==1/bbb
```

All rest, like a creation of superfunctions that refines your equation, is just sophistication..