# How to convert $a(x-p)^2+q$ to $a(x-\alpha+i\beta)(x-\alpha-i\beta)$ for any real $a$, $p$ and $q$

Tags: list-manipulation, factorization

I want to factorize any quadratic expressions into two complex-valued linear expressions.

My effort below

```
a := 1;(*needed*)
p := 2;(*needed*)
q := 3;(*needed*)
f[x_] := a (x - p)^2 + q;(*needed*)
AA := Coefficient[f[x], x^2];
BB := Coefficient[f[x], x];
CC := f[0];
DD = BB^2 - 4 AA CC;
EE = Times @@ (#[[1]] & /@ 
    Select[FactorInteger[DD], Mod[#[[2]], 2] == 1 &])
Factor[f[x], Extension -> Sqrt[EE]] // TeXForm (*needed*)
```

produces $\left(-i x+\sqrt{3}+2 i\right) \left(i x+\sqrt{3}-2
   i\right)$
rather than the expected $\left(x-2+i\sqrt{3}\right) \left(x-2-i\sqrt{3}\right)$.

## Question

How to convert $a(x-p)^2+q$ to $a(x-\alpha+i\beta)(x-\alpha-i\beta)$ for any real $a$, $p$ and $q$.

Note that  $a(x-\alpha+i\beta)(x-\alpha-i\beta)$ must be rendered with the leading $x$ **rather than** $a(-\alpha+i\beta+x)(-\alpha-i\beta+x)$.

## Edit

The order is **IMPORTANT**:
I need $a(x-\alpha+i\beta)(x-\alpha-i\beta)$

**NOT**
$a(-\alpha+i\beta+x)(-\alpha-i\beta+x)$

because it will be piped to `TeXForm`!

Comment: Why do you define `a:=1`?

Comment: Try this one `Times @@ (x - y /. Solve[f[y] == 0, y])`

Comment: @yarchik:  That'll work when `a = 1` but not otherwise.

Comment: @yarchik:  (though it would be easy to fix by multiplying by `a` at the end.)

Comment: @LetMeBeYourLostDisciple:  What would have happened if instead of defining a (and p and q), you simply wrote `f[x_]:= a (x - p)^2 + q`, to take one example?

Comment: @LetMeBeYourLostDisciple:  Recommendation:  Make your problem as *minimal* as possible, as you'll get more help.  "sake of my convenience" is precisely the PROBLEM! It is fine if you then take an answer and have to "change them back."  You're by no means the worst, but some OPs lazily post tons of code (for their convenience) when the problem involves just one line or one step.  Sure... it makes it easier for the OP, but much *harder* for the solvers.  Couldn't *all* your question be reduced to your second-to last sentence?  Well?  And all that *TeXForm* is definitely NOT needed.  See why?

Comment: Can't the TOTAL question be:  "How do I convert $(i x + a)(i x + b)$ to $(x + i c)(x + i d)$"?  That's it.  Done.  Once you have that answer you can plug in your particular `a`, etc.  Moreover, you won't get mixed up by solutions that *happen* to work with $a=1$ but not for $a \neq 1$.

Comment: `Times @@ Subtract @@@ Flatten @ Solve[f[x] == 0, x]` (see also Daniel Lichtblau’s answer to the linked duplicate).

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood you, but if you're going to pipe the result to `TeXForm` then it doesn't seem like the position of `x` should matter. Both `(x+1)(x+2)` and `(1+x)(2+x)` yield $(x+1) (x+2)$ when piped to `TeXForm`.

Comment: `Plus` is `Orderless`. You don't get to pick the position of `x`.  Perhaps you want something like `TraditionalForm`,  but like `TeXForm`, it formats output display, not the expression itself.

Comment: Do you mean something like `a (Times @@ Subtract @@@ Expand@Flatten@Solve[f[x] == 0, x])`?: [image of full code & output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9F7A.png)

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thank you for your very useful solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inelegant, but it'll work.  Basically we look at the coefficient of `x` in each factor, divide each factor by that coefficient, multiply all the `x` coefficients together as a leading coefficient for the factorization, and then multiply it all back together.

Use your code as above, then:

```
factors = FactorList[f[x], Extension -> Sqrt[EE]]
coeffs = Coefficient[#, x] & /@ Drop[factors[[All, 1]], 1]
factors[[2 ;; All, 1]] = Expand[factors[[2 ;; All, 1]]/coeffs]
factors[[1, 1]] = Times @@ coeffs
result = Times @@ Apply[Power, factors, 1]

(* (-2 - I Sqrt[3] + x) (-2 + I Sqrt[3] + x) *)
```

**EDIT:**

Note that when piped to TeXForm, Mathematica puts the terms in the factor in a more "traditional" order:

```
result // TeXForm
```

$$
\left(x-i \sqrt{3}-2\right) \left(x+i \sqrt{3}-2\right)$$

So unless I have misunderstood the goal, we do not need to worry about rearranging the terms in `result`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sol = SolveAlways[(I*x + a) (I*x + b) == e (x + I*c) (x + I*d), x]
(*    {{a -> -c, b -> -d, e -> -1}, {a -> -d, b -> -c, e -> -1}}    *)

e (x + I*c) (x + I*d) /. sol
(*    {-(I c + x) (I d + x), -(I c + x) (I d + x)}    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the coefficients of the expanded quadratics and solve:

```
cl1 = CoefficientList[(I*x + a) (I*x + b), x]
(* {a b,I a + I b,-1} *)
cl2 = CoefficientList[e (x + I*c) (x + I*d), x]
(* {-c d e, I c e + I d e, e} *)

sol = Solve[MapThread[Equal, {cl1, cl2}], {c, d, e}]
(* {{c -> -a, d -> -b, e-> -1},{c -> -b, d -> -a, e -> -1}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

substituting and inverse-substituting

```
((I*x + a) (I*x + b) /. {a -> I ai, b -> I bi}  // Factor) 
/. {ai -> -I a, bi -> I b}
(*-((-I a + x) (I b + x))*)
```

works too

Answer (score 1):

There are already several nice solutions published here. Let me put also my five cents.
Let

```
expr = (-I x + a + b*I)*(I x + a - b*I)
```

be our expression.

I often use the function to take the desired factor out of the parentheses:

```
factor[expr_, fact_, funExpr_ : Expand, funFact_ : Identity] := 
 Module[{a = fact, b = expr/fact},
  funFact[Evaluate[a]]*funExpr[Evaluate[b]]]
```

I already published it with the description, for example, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249929/how-to-extract-a-factor-from-equation-and-rearrange-the-equation/249937#249937)

With this function one acts as follows:

```
MapAt[factor[#, I] &, expr, {{1}, {2}}]

(*  -((-I a + b - x) (-I a - b + x))  *)
```

Have fun!